# how to extract frame by frame from live stream with rtmp server

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

I am using rtmp https://github.com/theintencity/rtmplite as live stream server. I want to get frame by frame from streaming data. Actually in the server had function to save stream to *.flv* file (input is byte stream data) in function `write` from line `673` to `686` what I want is also input is byte stream data but the output is frame by frame so that I can process on each frame.

Below is the function I am working on

```
def write(self, message):
    '''Write a message to the file, assuming it was opened for writing or appending.'''
    # if message.type == Message.VIDEO:
    # self.videostarted = True
    # elif not hasattr(self, "videostarted"): return
    if message.type == Message.AUDIO or message.type == Message.VIDEO:
        length, ts = message.size, message.time
        #if _debug: print 'FLV.write()', message.type, ts
        if self.tsr0 is None: self.tsr0 = ts - self.tsr1
        self.tsr, ts = ts, ts - self.tsr0
        # if message.type == Message.AUDIO: print 'w', message.type, ts
        data = struct.pack('>BBHBHB', message.type, (length >> 16) & 0xff, length & 0x0ffff, (ts >> 16) & 0xff, ts & 0x0ffff, (ts >> 24) & 0xff) + '\x00\x00\x00' +  message.data
        data += struct.pack('>I', len(data))
        self.fp.write(data)
```

The output of `message.data` (truncated) look like below
`data="2\x00\x00\x84\x0fC?\xff\x9c\x1d\xfc&An\xf9\xc2\x18\xfc4\xbe\xf0\x8a\n\xa7\xd5\x03\x00\xe2\x0c\x03\x18\x94\x08\x01\x0f\xe2@\x1e\x1f\xfe\xfb;$\x93\xb3fo\xfa\x94\xf3\xec\nxZ\xc3k\x08\xfc\xcd\x04{g\xfa\xc4AA\xa4~\xeeo\x1b0#\xecR\x98\x0b_\x080\xac\x9a\xf5pi@\xa4\xae\x87\xce'\xab\xf5c65\xcd...(704)`

I don't know how to get a frame of this stream, means a frame should begin from which byte to which byte, and how can we know it.

I am very appreciate if anyone can give me some suggestions or hints. Thank you

Comment: were you able to find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

FLV is documentation is publicly available

https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf